# Using PHP to print to HTML5 output tag

Tags: php, html

I am new to this.  If I have some PHP code as in the example below, I can use the echo function to print the result.  Echo always prints at the top of the screen.  How do I format the tag so that in this case the result "$myPi" is printed to the screen using an HTML5 output tag? I am a newbie so please be kind to me and don't flame my post - I tried to format the code.  Thanks QJB.

```
    function taylorSeriesPi($Iteration)
    {
        $count = 0;
        $myPi = 0.0;
        for ($count=0; ($count<$Iteration);$count++)
        {
            if ( ($count%4) == 1)
            {
                $myPi = $myPi + (1/$count);
            }
            if ( ($count%4) == 3)
            {
                $myPi = $myPi - (1/$count);
            }
        }
        $myPi *= 4.0;

        echo ("Pi is ". $myPi. " After ".$Iteration. " iterations");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert PHP anywhere in your document, and reference functions from any other place within the document or included files.

For example:

```
<?php
    function taylorSeriesPi($Iteration)
    {
        $count = 0;
        $myPi = 0.0;
        for ($count=0; ($count<$Iteration);$count++)
        {
            ...
        }
        $myPi *= 4.0;

        // Return the value so we can use this function later.
        return $myPi;
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="somediv">
            <?php
                $iteration = 6/*or whatever*/;
                echo "Pi is " . taylorSeriesPi($iteration) . " After " . $iteration . " iterations";
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will put the returned value and associated string within the `<div>` tag, but you can put it anywhere in your HTML, as the output of the echo will simply be text by the time the markup is seen by your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I have been trying to fathom this out for a while. :)